# prevent ng-repeat from showing images when there is no data

Tags: angularjs

On most of our angular pages we got this annoying error and we cant seem to find a solution.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/img/flagNations/%7B%7B%20bookings.language%20%7D%7D.png 404 (Not Found)
```

The code is ok, and the error only appears when there is no data in ng-repeat.

```
vm.checkinTodayShowAll = false;

if (res.checkinToday.length) {
  vm.checkinTodayShowAll = true;
  vm.checkinToday = res.checkinToday; 
}
```

and on the page I even hide it if there is no data...

```
<table class="start-table start-checkin-table" ng-show="vm.checkinTodayShowAll">
```

But still it wants to render that image

```
<tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.checkinToday" class="start-text">
  <td class="start-left start-border overflow">
    <img src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.language }}.png" class="start-flag">
  </td>
</tr>
```

How do we prevent it from trying to render the image when there is nothing to `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-if instead of ng-show

```
<table class="start-table start-checkin-table"  ng-if="vm.checkinTodayShowAll.length > 0">
 <tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.checkinToday" class="start-text">
    <td class="start-left start-border overflow">
        <img src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.language }}.png" class="start-flag">
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: it should be :`vm.checkinTodayShowAll.length > 0`  not 1

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`:

```
<table class="start-table start-checkin-table" ng-if="vm.checkinTodayShowAll.length>0">
```

instead of:

```
<table class="start-table start-checkin-table" ng-show="vm.checkinTodayShowAll">
```

> `ng-show:` Just hides the view   It is still in DOM .
>  `ng-if:` Remove
>   element from DOM

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-if`

```
<tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.checkinToday" class="start-text">
    <td class="start-left start-border overflow">
        <img src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.language }}.png" ng-if="vm.checkinToday.length > 0" class="start-flag">
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Try this one and it will boost performance also
<table class="start-table start-checkin-table" ng-if="vm.checkinTodayShowAll.length">  
<tr ng-repeat="bookings in vm.checkinToday track by $index" class="start-text">
<td class="start-left start-border overflow">
    <img src="./img/flagNations/{{ bookings.language }}.png" class="starflag">
</td>
```